# Ruby: Arranging larger classes/files

Tags: ruby

I'm aware that ruby class files should generally be quite small, but sometimes I find logic in classes that (a) don't really warrant their own file, but (b) would be more readable if I could group them somehow.

For example, in certain classes I may have (let's say) 10 methods which determine paths. At the moment, I tend to just throw some a few lines of decorative "### PATHS ###" type comments around them to distinguish them from the rest of the group. I'm wondering if theres a better way(?)

Am I right in thinking implementing subclasses/modules within a class just to improve readability is a little excessive, or do other folks do this? Any other thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they *do* warrant their own file -  Think single responsibility principle.   Since you haven't shown us any code, here's an idea for a separate class that handles the paths for an object:

```
class FooPaths
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def path_one
     # code to calculate path using @foo
  end

  def path_two
    #code to calculate another path using @foo
  end
end
```

The idea is that your class `Foo` is probably doing too many things.   Create smaller classes which accept @foo in the initializer, and then that smaller class can handle a smaller subset of operations involving Foo.   It's also a lot easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a bunch of similar helper methods, that means one of two things.

1. I have a business concept (read: object) that needs to be defined
2. I have a bunch of business concepts that act in a similar way.

For the first case, very often, the first argument passed into the method is the name of the business concept

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # active record attributes :first_name, :last_name

  def self.full_name(first_name, last_name)
    [first_name, last_name].compact.join(" ") 
  end

  def self.extract_first_name(full_name)
    full_name.split.first
  end
end
```

So I would create a concept for `full_name`:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  # active record attributes :first_name, :last_name
  def full_name
    FullName.from_parts(first_name, last_name)
  end

  def full_name=(val)
    if val
      self.first_name, self_last_name = val.partsfirst_name, val.last_name
    else
      self.first_name = self.last_name = nil
    end
  end
end

class FullName
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
  def to_s
    parts.join(" ") 
  end

  def parts
    [first_name, last_name].compact
  end

  def eq(other)
    to_s.eq(other)
  end

  def self.from_parts(first_name, last_name)
    # [...]
  end
  def self.from_full_name(full_name)
    # [...]
  end
end
```

I know the example is contrived, but I've found that a lot of view logic and helpers groups around this concept. So if you end up finding more concepts that can be brought into this, or you notice that you often pass these around in groups, then it is a great candidate. Also, if you have had a number of conversations with the business users around the full name of a user, then that is really saying that you want a business concept here.

For the second case, it is sometimes the case that you want to add "the same" attribute onto a bunch of disparate business objects. They just happen to be calculated in different ways. The path for a chapter book and a dictionary are different. Introduce the concept of a chapter book and a dictionary, both having the path parameter. As stated above, if you find that you are not using these business concepts often with your users, chances are, this is not the right approach here.